# How many documents can be written in batch mode from firebase cloud function trigger to Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have large amount of data where we need to update documents based on a status. We will writing in batch of 500 chunks and wondering how many max records we can commit with a single trigger invocation?

Our trigger is a pubsub trigger in firebase cloud functions.

We see there is a limit of 540secs per invocation so would like to know how many max documents we can write in batches?

Update : Adding usecase

I have an event collection(Events) where users can subscribe for each event happening in a country.

Users have an api to see how many events they have subscribed to. They have query flags like is the event Live/Finished/Upcoming.

As I can't save list of user array who subscribed for an event in the event document(assuming subscribers can go beyond the document limit when stored), I maintained a separate sub-collection under users collection. 
Ex : users/user-id/subscribedevents

Event document's status (Live/Finished/Upcoming), i'm updating from a cron job which will be running every minute. This is because I can't apply filters with two different fields (startDate & endDate).

When ever an event's status changes, i need to update in subscribedevents subcollection (which is under user's collection).

As I will be updating all the subscribedevents subcollection entries, I want to do it in batches.

Hope the usecase gives some clarity on where it is applied. As firestore is designed for scale, wondering how others are handling this scenario as its very common.

Comment: The documented limits for Cloud Firestore don't change when performed from Cloud Functions as compared to mobile, web, or server environments. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions

Comment: Maximum write rate to a document  1 per sec => Does this mean for 540sec, we can write only 540 documents? Is it the same case when using batches (with each batch containing 500 doc changes)?

Comment: That limit refers to the rate at which you can write to a **single document** repeatedly, not a batch of documents.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Doug!
Do you have any numbers on how many batches possible in 540secs? Actually we couldn't save an array list in one document as its limited to 1mb. so the array list entries are moved to a separate collection but need to handle the changes in the original document. For this we are writing a database trigger to update all the subcollection entries. This subcollection can be nearly million documents.

I see this can be an usual scenario when database has higher volume.

Comment: I don't think Firestore can guarantee a minimum document write throughput, batched or not, from any source.  You could benchmark it to see what limit is reasonable.

Comment: If you're concerned about the amount of time it takes to perform all these batches, maybe Cloud Functions isn't the right way to go about it.  Or consider breaking up your batches into known sizes and split all that work up among several function invocations.

Comment: Let me do a benchmark and update here. I hope doing for 10 batch writes of 500 count and averaging might give some values to start with or atleast some approximation. Thanks Doug! Always helpful :)

Comment: I wish sometime there will be an increase in the size of document from 1 MB to at-least 3-5MB. Else we need to do lot of stuff just to have the data synced in proper state. My usecase here is to find out how many users subscribed for a particular event. I have a method like getSubscribedEvents (queried from an user)and event collection states keep changing. But, I remember you mentioning there will be a cost for scaling which we totally accept :) . Just worried if firestore can handle even we take the overhead approach.

Answer (score -1):

Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents.
And 20 maximum batched writes.

References

[Firestore Write Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions)

[Transaction and batches in firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: What does "20 maximum batched writes" mean?

Comment: I don't think the it mentions about number of batches possible. @DougStevenson waiting for your answer :)

Comment: @DougStevenson Please have a look at this
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#security_rules

Comment: The max number of document gets of 20 in security rules isn't relevant to this question, as the question isn't asking about security rules at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for pointing it out. I found the solution from this. As per the question, this may be the answer. Please have a look at the link. 
 `A batched write can contain up to 500 operations` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: I believe the original question is already stating that they're batching documents in groups of 500. If you look at the comment history in the question, it seems they have a slightly different question.